# Почему блок с overflow: hidden встаёт рядом?

Tags: html, css

Если у блока выставлено `overflow: hidden`, он встаёт рядом с float'ом, а не накрывается им. Почему так? И как вообще overflow взаимодействует с размещением блоков?

```css
section { 
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 4px solid burlywood;
}

section:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  background: rgba(160, 160, 160, .5);
  border: 4px dotted red;
}

div {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>Float</aside>
  <div style="overflow: hidden">2</div>
</section>

<section>
  <aside>Float</aside>
  <div style="overflow: visible">2</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правила обтекания для `float` применяются внутри [одного блочного контекста форматирования](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). Блочные элементы, у которых `overflow` имеет значение отличное от `visible` получают новый блочный контекст форматирования.

Почему это важно, можно увидеть в статье "[MDN: overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)".

> Это технически необходимо, поскольку если бы `float` пересекался с
>   элементом прокрутки, это потребовало бы обеспечить обтекание
>   содержимого прокручиваемого элемента вокруг вторгающихся float'ов.
>   Обтекание при этом было бы необходимо производить после каждого шага
>   прокрутки заново, что привело бы к заметному замедлению прокрутки.

Кроме того, блочный контекст форматирования может быть создан посредством:

> - корневого элемента или чего-то, что содержит его
> - поплавков (элементы, у которых `float` не равно `none`)
> - абсолютно позиционированных элементов (элементами, значение `position` которых либо `absolute`, либо `fixed`)
> - строчных блоков (элементы с `display: inline-block`)
> - ячеек таблиц (элементы с `display: table-cell`, установленным по умолчанию для ячеек таблицы)
> - заголовков таблиц (элементы с `display: table-caption`, установленным по умолчанию для заголовков таблицы)
> - элементов, у которых значение свойства `overflow` отличается от `visible`
> - flex блоков (элементы с `display: flex` или `inline-flex`)